# xpath condition to descendants

Tags: xml, xpath, lxml

I have next xml sample structure

```
<root>

<rec xmlns="some_url">
<itemNumber>
<number>1</number>
</itemNumber>
</rec>

<rec>
<itemNumber>
<number>2</number>
</itemNumber>
</rec>

<rec>
<itemNumber>
<number>2</number>
</itemNumber>
</rec>

</root>
```

The problem is that here is `xmlns` and to find some element I need to find it by local name. For example to find all `<rec>` elements:

```
root.xpath("*[local-name() = 'rec']")
```

To find all `itemNumber`:

```
root.xpath("*[local-name() = 'rec']/*[local-name() = 'itemNumber']")
```

The main barrier is  namespaces. But don't advice me on removing namespaces, because my xml document is very huge and it will take additional time.
I need to return `<rec>` elements that fits condition, for example where `<number>` equals to 2. In this case it will return

```
<rec>
<itemNumber>
<number>1</number>
</itemNumber>
</rec>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that here is xmlns...

Using namespaces is nothing especially difficult [with `lxml`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes).

In XPath calls, you just need to pass a `namespaces` argument with a prefix mapped to this `some_url`. Then you just need to use that prefix in front of element names.

Example ipython session:

```
In [1]: import lxml.etree

In [2]: doc = lxml.etree.fromstring("""<root>

<rec xmlns="some_url">
<itemNumber>
<number>1</number>
</itemNumber>
</rec>

<rec>
<itemNumber>
<number>2</number>
</itemNumber>
</rec>

<rec>
<itemNumber>
<number>2</number>
</itemNumber>
</rec>

</root>""")

In [3]: doc.xpath('ns:rec[ns:itemNumber=1]', namespaces={"ns": "some_url"})
Out[3]: [<Element {some_url}rec at 0x7f358cccd2d8>]

In [4]:
```